# SpriteKit: How to draw custom shapes without SKShapeNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

From Apples class reference for SKShapeNode's but also from many developers i hear that using SKShapeNode for drawing custom shapes you want to draw often on the view is a bad idea because it performs bad.

Its true, a simple app with some custom shapes is spiking my CPU up to 80% and using like 80MB RAM (on devices its a bit better).

So then, how do i draw shapes like arrows without using SKShapeNode, because i like the idea to draw with bezierpaths since i do not need to care about display size.

How to draw an arrow with a texture without getting a bad quality, since it would stretch my image when i move my touch stretching the arrow. Doing this with SKShapeNode works perfect but performs bad.

Comment: "on devices its a bit better" And what else you have been running your app on? Don't take Simulator into account. Users won't run your app on sim :) Also you may convert shapes to textures as pointed but you should probably do that before your gameplay starts. Otherwise you may experience lag as well because those conversions to textures are expensive....

Answer (score 3):

You can always have one `SKShapeNode` node available that you use for creating shapes, and use the `path` property to design the shape. Then create a texture out of the SKShapeNode from the scenes view with `let texture = scene.view.textureFromNode(shapeNode)` and place the new texture into an `SKSpriteNode`

Comment: yeah i know, i do that already. but i have the feeling this is not really helping much. my CPU is still high at 60-80%. I did that for a simple tile layer showing like 13 tiles which i built up from SKShapeNodes. The draw count now shows only 13 draws. NOTHING is happening on that screen only showing the 13 tiles, but my CPU is at 65% and RAM usage at about 70MB. Am i doing something wrong. Converting from shape to sprite is very easy, so im sure im not doing anything wrong with the conversion.

Comment: Couldn't tell you,  if all you have are sprites and you have 65% cpu usage, then you need to evaluate the code

Comment: @KnightOfDragon - This is a great technique and I implemented successfully in my app. But, I need to create around 60 circle textures from SKShapeNode arcs. When I do there is a memory error on some devices that do not have enough ram. Do you know a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: No idea what you are doing   60 circles is nothing,  you probably have retain cycles happening

Comment: I make GameOfLife, which contains thousands of node. Is it possible to draw square instead of Add New Node or update Added Node ? (In Single View Draw multiple Square / custom shape / lines / pixelHandling)(like Python-Turtle)

Comment: if you arent't going to use the nodes, then maybe not use sprite kit.